# Creating a namedtuple object using only a subset of arguments passed

Tags: python, arguments, decorator, namedtuple

I am pulling rows from a MySQL database as dictionaries (using SSDictCursor) and doing some processing, using the following approach:

```
from collections import namedtuple

class Foo(namedtuple('Foo', ['id', 'name', 'age'])):
    __slots__ = ()

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(self, *args)

    # ...some class methods below here

class Bar(namedtuple('Bar', ['id', 'address', 'city', 'state']):
    __slots__ = ()

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(Bar, self).__init__(self, *args)

    # some class methods here...

# more classes for distinct processing tasks...
```

To use `namedtuple`, I have to know exactly the fields I want beforehand, which is fine. However, I would like to allow the user to feed a simple `SELECT *` statement into my program, which will then iterate through the rows of the result set, performing multiple tasks using these different classes. In order to make this work, my classes have to somehow examine the N fields coming in from the cursor and take only the particular subset M < N corresponding to the names expected by the `namedtuple` definition.

My first thought was to try writing a single decorator that I could apply to each of my classes, which would examine the class to see what fields it was expecting, and pass only the appropriate arguments to the new object. But I've just started reading about decorators in the past few days, and I'm not that confident yet with them.

So my question is in two parts:

1. Is this possible to do with a single decorator, that will figure out which fields are needed by the specific class being decorated?
2. Is there an alternative with the same functionality that will be easier to use, modify and understand?

I have too many potential permutations of tables and fields, with millions of rows in each result set, to just write one all-purpose `namedtuple` subclass to deal with each different task. Query time and available memory have proven to be limiting factors.

If needed:

```
>>> sys.version
'2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:43:36) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you have to override `__new__` in order to customize `namedtuple` creation, because a `namedtuple`'s `__new__` method checks its arguments before you even get to `__init__`.

Second, if your goal is to accept and filter keyword arguments, you need to take `**kwargs` and filter and pass that through, not just `*args`.

So, putting it together:

```
class Foo(namedtuple('Foo', ['id', 'name', 'age'])):
    __slots__ = ()

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs = {k: v for k, v in kwargs.items() if k in cls._fields}
        return super(Foo, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
```

---

You could replace that dict comprehension with `itemgetter`, but every time I use itemgetter with multiple keys, nobody understands what it means, so I've reluctantly stopped using it.

---

You can also override `__init__` if you have a reason to do so, because it will be called as soon as `__new__` returns a `Foo` instance.

But you don't need to just for this, because the namedtuple's `__init__` doesn't take any arguments or do anything; the values have already been set in `__new__` (just as with `tuple`, and other immutable types). It looks like with CPython 2.7, you actually *can* `super(Foo, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)` and it'll just be ignored, but with PyPy 1.9 and CPython 3.3, you get a TypeError. At any rate, there's no reason to pass them, and nothing saying it should work, so don't do it even in CPython 2.7.

Note that you `__init__` will get the unfiltered `kwargs`. If you want to change that, you could mutate `kwargs` in-place in `__new__`, instead of making a new dictionary. But I believe that still isn't guaranteed to do anything; it just makes it implementation-defined whether you get the filtered args or unfiltered, instead of guaranteeing the unfiltered.

---

So, can you wrap this up? Sure!

```
def LenientNamedTuple(name, fields):
    class Wrapper(namedtuple(name, fields)):
        __slots__ = ()
        def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
            args = args[:len(fields)]
            kwargs = {k: v for k, v in kwargs.items() if k in fields}
            return super(Wrapper, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    return Wrapper
```

Note that this has the advantage of not having to use the quasi-private/semi-documented `_fields` class attribute, because we already have `fields` as a parameter.

Also, while we're at it, I added a line to toss away any excess positional arguments, as suggested in a comment.

---

Now you just use it as you'd use `namedtuple`, and it automatically ignores any excess arguments:

```
class Foo(LenientNamedTuple('Foo', ['id', 'name', 'age'])):
    pass

print(Foo(id=1, name=2, age=3, spam=4))
```

print(Foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
    print(Foo(1, age=3, name=2, eggs=4))

---

I've uploaded [a test](http://pastebin.com/Anp9GW5b), replacing the dict comprehension with `dict()` on a genexpr for 2.6 compatibility (2.6 is the earliest version with `namedtuple`), but without the args truncating. It works with positional, keyword, and mixed args, including out-of-order keywords, in CPython 2.6.7, 2.7.2, 2.7.5, 3.2.3, 3.3.0, and 3.3.1, PyPy 1.9.0 and 2.0b1, and Jython 2.7b.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the detail. However, I'm not seeing how to declare `Foo` with one set of fields and `Bar` with another set of fields, when they're hard-coded in the `Wrapper` class?

Comment: After some experimenting, it seems to work with `class Wrapper(namedtuple(name, fields))`. Can't reliably take args-only or mixed args/kwargs any more, but that's not an issue for me. If that line was just a goof, please edit and I will accept.

Comment: @AirThomas: Where can't it take args-only or mixed args? I just tested it on every Python I have, in every combination of args I could think of, and it always works as expected. See the link in the edited answer.

Comment: It doesn't take args-only when `len(args) != len(fields)`. I think I was mistaken about mixed, that seems to work fine. I'm guessing what's happening is that declaring any keywords at all prompts non-keyword arguments to be parsed implicitly in kwargs as well.

Comment: Could certainly handle `len(args) > len(fields)` inside `LenientNamedTuple.__new__` (e.g. by truncating) and leave `len(args) < len(fields)` alone. I think for my purposes I'll disallow non-keyword args entirely, though. Per the zen: explicit, simple.

Comment: @AirThomas: Experiment with a simple function: `def foo(*args, **kwargs): print(args, kwargs)`; it's a lot easier than trying to figure out the nooks and crannies of the rules by reading the docs. (Personally, I pretty frequently forget one of the 2.x-vs.-3.x differences, and fire up an interpreter to find out.) But anyway, good idea about too many positional args—although you can do it a bit more simply; let me edit the answer. You can't really allow too few args, unless you want to supply some default value.

Comment: I should clarify that by "leave it alone" I meant let it continue to throw an exception. :)

Answer (score 3):

A `namedtuple` type has an attribute `_fields` which is a tuple of the names of the fields in the object. You could use this to dig out the required fields from the database record.

Answer (score 3):

These answers all seem overly-complex. Do you really want new classes and overloading instead of just writing a line of code or a helper function to instantiate a standard datatype the way you want?

```
Foo = namedtuple('Foo', ['id', 'name', 'age'], defaults=(None,) * 3)
Bar = namedtuple('Bar', ['id', 'address', 'city', 'state'], defaults=(None,) * 4)

poo = {'id': 1, 'age': 'Orz', 'city': 'Tucson', 'weight': True}
ooh = {'id': 2, 'name': 'Spathi', 'state': 'Iowa', 'children': '25'}
```

```
>>> Foo(*[poo[f] if f in poo else None for f in Foo._fields])
Foo(id=1, name=None, age='Orz')
```

Ta-daa!

Or make a little helper.

```
# nt should have defaults
def nt_from_kwargs(nt, **kwargs):
    return nt(**dict(i for i in kwargs.items() if i[0] in nt._fields))
```

```
>>> nt_from_kwargs(Foo, id=1, age='Orz', city='Tucson', weight=True)
Foo(id=1, name=None, age='Orz')

>>> nt_from_kwargs(Bar, **poo)
Bar(id=1, address=None, city='Tucson', state=None)

>>> nt_from_kwargs(Bar, **{**poo, **ooh})
Bar(id=2, address=None, city='Tucson', state='Iowa')
```

And everybody likes dictionaries.

```
def nt_from_dict(nt, d):
    return nt(*[d[k] if k in d else None for k in nt._fields])
```

```
>>> nt_from_dict(Foo, poo)
Foo(id=1, name=None, age='Orz')

>>> nt_from_dict(Bar, poo)
Bar(id=1, address=None, city='Tucson', state=None)

>>> nt_from_dict(Bar, {**poo, **ooh})
Bar(id=2, address=None, city='Tucson', state='Iowa')
```